# Knockout move/slide highlighted selection CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am using Knockout and jQuery, there are 3 title headers which can be selected, as default the first title in selected and a pill-like background CSS for it is defined so can visually identify which option is selected.

When another option is selected then the new option will have the pill-like highlight. What I need is the pill-like selection to slide transition/animate smoothly across to which ever the new option is selected. The HTML code I have is

```
<div data-bind="foreach:sortLabels,selectedSlide:selectedSortLabel">
     <a class="btn" data-bind="text:label.toUpperCase(), css:{'selected':$parent.selectedSortLabel()==$data}, click:$parent.selectedSortLabel"></a>
</div>
```

So I have an array `sortLabels` which has 2 attributes: `label` and `filter`. The above loops round and displays each `label` in uppercase and also applies the css style `selected` based on which `label` is selected stored in `selectedSortLabel`. `selectedSortLabel` is the selected object. in my appModel the JavaScript I have defined above variables:

```
self.sortLabels = ko.observableArray([
     { label: "A B C", filter: 'abc' }, { label: "D E F", filter: 'def' }, { label: "G H I", filter: 'ghi' },
     { label: "J K L", filter: 'jkl' }, { label: "M N O", filter: 'mno' }, { label: "P Q R", filter: 'pqr' },
     { label: "S T U", filter: 'stu' }, { label: "V W X", filter: 'vwx' }, { label: "Y Z 0-9", filter: 'yz09' },
]);

self.selectedSortLabel = ko.observable(self.sortLabels()[0]);
```

I was advised by a colleague to create custom binding like

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectedSlide = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        valueAccessor().subscribe(function () {
            console.log("changed from ", value);
            console.log("change to ", modelApp.selectedSortLabel());
        });
    }
};
```

using something like `$("pointer").animate({ left: "100px" }, 2000)`

CSS:

```
.selected {
    -webkit-border-radius: 40;
    -moz-border-radius: 40;
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: #656565;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;

    background: #C4C4C4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I don't have a clue how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, a div was needed, css background pill needed to be separated and updated with selected option's position in each update defined in custom binding.